# Как устранить ошибку при создании директорий с помощью библиотеки os python?

Tags: python-3.x, ос

Написал код, для создания директорий:

```
import os

def creating_directory(dir_name):
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Ishmu\Desktop\Акварель\Data\Акварель')
    try:
        # создание папки
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
        print("Папка " , dir_name ,  " создана") 
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Папка " , dir_name ,  " уже существует или невозможно создать")

creating_directory('Акварельные рисунки')
```

Но постоянно выскакивает ошибка:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-071178dc717f>", line 4
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Ishmu\Desktop\Акварель\Data\Акварель')
            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `\U` читается как экранированное U. Нужно или экранировать слэши или поставить r перед строкой:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Ishmu\Desktop\Акварель\Data\Акварель')
```

или

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Ishmu\\Desktop\\Акварель\\Data\\Акварель')
```

Answer (score -1):

Долго погуглив нашел ответ, дело было в обратных слешах:

```
import os

def creating_directory(dir_name):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Ishmu\\Desktop\\Акварель\\Data\\Акварель')
    try:
        # создание папки
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
        print("Папка " , dir_name ,  " создана") 
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Папка " , dir_name ,  " уже существует или невозможно создать")

creating_directory('Акварельные рисунки')
```